# How to convert regex "x{m, n}" to NFA?

Tags: regex, parsing, nfa

The regex `x{m, n}` matches from `m` to `n` repetitions of the preceding `x`, attempting to match as many as possible.

I have a naive solution, but the number of nodes and edges depends on `m` and `n`, which is unacceptable when `n` is big.

So, is there any effective way to convert the regex to *NFA*?

Comment: Improved question format for highlighting variables and the regex as code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the NFA is going to be big.  The DFA, if you're building one, is going to be big too.  This is inescapable by the Myhill-Nerode theorem

Comment: Your naïve solution is likely the correct one. NFAs deal badly with many repetitions. Luckily this is rare situation in real-life applications of NFAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, NFAs don't "count" very well. You're essentially going to have to manually expand your regex to something Thompsons' construction can handle. e.g.

```
m{2,5} -> mm(m(m(m)?)?)?
```

Search for the function `SimplifyRepeat` [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/6272edcb53d3c8705f57df3b46b1f92e646e30bc/re2/simplify.cc#L579) to see Google's implementation. See [this page](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html) for more information on regex implementation in practice.

Comment: Wow, that code is like a free advertisement for C++11. `Incref()` ugh.

Comment: Thank you very much, though I'm surprised that the navie solution is the best solution :)